# CentOS 7 pg_upgrade Permissions Errors

Tags: postgresql, pg-upgrade

I'm trying to migrate PostgreSQL from 9.2 to 10.2 on CentOS 7

I've installed the new version, and I'm trying to implement the changeover:

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/data/ --new-datadir /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/ \
--old-bindir /usr/bin/ --new-bindir /usr/pgsql-10/bin/
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
could not open version file: /var/lib/pgsql/data/PG_VERSION
Failure, exiting
```

I try as root, and `pg_upgrade` cannot be run as root.

`/var/lib/pgsql` belongs to **postgres:postgres** so I'm at a bit of a loss how I can get this done.

Do I have to be a certain user to upgrade PostgreSQL using `pg_upgrade`?  How do I proceed to get this switched over to v10.2?   I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking and simple.

Comment: Did you initialize the Postgres 10 data directory using `/usr/pgsql-10/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/data` before running pg_upgrade?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I did.  As it stands, starting `PostgreSQL` still launches `9.2`.  So as I see it, the switchover to `10` is the only issue, which seems a permissions thing.

Answer (score 0):

You must run `pg_upgrade` as the user that owns both the new and the old data directories. That user is typically `postgres`.

If `/var/lib/pgsql/data/PG_VERSION` does not exist, `/var/lib/pgsql/data` is no PostgreSQL data directory.