# redhat pg_upgrade permission errors

Tags: postgresql, redhat, pg-upgrade

duplicate of unanswered question:

[CentOS 7 pg_upgrade Permissions Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166580/centos-7-pg-upgrade-permissions-errors)

when trying to run pg_upgrade, it won't let me run the command as root. when exiting from root, it can't access files due to permissions. how can this be solved?

command i'm running:

```
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/ --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-12/bin/ --old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/ --new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/
```

error message when running command as root:

```
pg_upgrade: cannot be run as root
Failure, exiting
```

error message when not running command as root:

```
could not open version file: /var/lib/pgsql/10/data/PG_VERSION
Failure, exiting
```

also tried to run command as postgres user

```
su postgres

/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/ --new-bindir=/usr/pgsql-12/bin/ --old-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/ --new-datadir=/var/lib/pgsql/12/data

could not change directory to "/home/j.d": Permission denied

could not open log file "pg_upgrade_internal.log": Permission denied
Failure, exiting
```

Comment: Could you please provide details of your specific problem?  i.e., are your version and paths the same as that other post?  If not, then we need to see what your specific environment looks like

Comment: I have answered the other question. That should help you.

Comment: so i have tried that but it gives an error as well, i'll add it to the post

Comment: I think part of the problem is that when you ran `pg_upgrade` as root and as the other user, the files got created with those users' ownership (i.e., `pg_upgrade_internal.log).  Now, you run `pg_upgrade` as `postgres`, and it can't access those files because they're owned by `root` and/or `j.d`.  Try clearing out those files before running `pg_upgrade` again

Comment: i am facing same issue